Is Reverse lookup of Country to IP ranges supported in Maxmind databases?
I understood the way to query a country name by passing an IP address. But I'm also looking to get ip ranges by passing the country code. my question is, is this possible with the Maxmind database?
I tried using libmaxminddb and GeoIP2-Python to understand if the "country to ip ranges" is supported or not. I couldn't find any supporting code for the same. I just wanted to confirm it here.
